# Subdivide multiple faces at once?

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface, shortcut

I would like to Subdivide several faces at once? and vertically, without having to make a face by a face, I would like to know how to do for future larger modeling

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you select only the horizontal edges (in edge selection mode of course), you can use the subdivide tool.

Comment: As @FFeller said - the hint "in edge selection mode of course" is very important in this case. Since your faces are connected through mutual vertices, would you try to select the horizontal edges in vertex select mode, the vertical edges would be selected too, because if you select vertices at the top and the bottom Blender doesn't know that you don't want to select the vertical edges inbetween.

Comment: yes indeed, thank you so much